# Hadoop slows down after map 100%

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am running a test on a 5 node cluster, on hadoop 1.0.3. The test consists of a chain of 3 jobs. The first job runs perfectly. The second job takes the output of the first job (around 100MB). After the mapping smoothly gets to a 100%, the job gets stuck in between the map phase and the reduce phase. It takes a lot of time to get the reduce to 5%. Here's the complete Hadoop output with the times.

```
13/11/19 13:39:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:40:12 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 1% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:40:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 2% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:40:24 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 3% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:40:29 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 4% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:40:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 5% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:40:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 6% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:40:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 7% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:41:01 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 8% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:41:06 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 9% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:41:18 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 10% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:41:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 11% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:41:33 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 12% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:41:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 13% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:41:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 14% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:41:55 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 15% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:42:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 16% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:42:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 17% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:42:18 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 18% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:42:29 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 19% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:42:36 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 20% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:42:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 21% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:42:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 22% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:42:57 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 23% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:43:07 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 24% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:43:17 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 25% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:43:27 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 26% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:43:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 27% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:43:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 28% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:43:54 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 29% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:44:03 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 30% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:44:12 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 31% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:44:18 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 32% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:44:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 33% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:44:38 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 34% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:44:48 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 35% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:44:54 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 36% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:45:02 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 37% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:45:16 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 38% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:45:21 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 39% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:45:33 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 40% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:45:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 41% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:45:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 42% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:45:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 43% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:46:06 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 44% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:46:17 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 45% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:46:23 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 46% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:46:32 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 47% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:46:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 48% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:46:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 49% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:46:54 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 50% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:47:01 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 51% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:47:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 52% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:47:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 53% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:47:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 54% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:47:36 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 55% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:47:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 56% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:47:59 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 57% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:48:02 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 58% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:48:14 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 59% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:48:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 60% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:48:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 61% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:48:48 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 62% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:48:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 63% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:49:07 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 64% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:49:17 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 65% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:49:27 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 66% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:49:36 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 67% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:49:45 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 68% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:49:55 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 69% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:50:03 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 70% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:50:17 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 71% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:50:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 72% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:50:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 73% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:50:46 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 74% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:50:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 75% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:51:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 76% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:51:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 77% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:51:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 78% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:51:33 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 79% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:51:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 80% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:51:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 81% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:52:02 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 82% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:52:07 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 83% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:52:18 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 84% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:52:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 85% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:52:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 86% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:52:54 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 87% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:53:06 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 88% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:53:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 89% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:53:32 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 90% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:53:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 91% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:53:54 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 92% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:54:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 93% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:54:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 94% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:54:34 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 95% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:54:49 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 96% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:55:12 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 97% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:55:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 98% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:56:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 99% reduce 0%
13/11/19 13:56:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
13/11/19 14:19:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 1%
13/11/19 14:23:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 2%
13/11/19 14:25:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 3%
13/11/19 14:31:12 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 4%
13/11/19 14:34:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 5%
13/11/19 14:35:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 89% reduce 5%
13/11/19 14:46:54 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 79% reduce 5%
13/11/19 14:46:55 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 79% reduce 6%
13/11/19 14:53:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 79% reduce 7%
13/11/19 14:56:08 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 79% reduce 8%
13/11/19 14:56:50 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201310311057_0040_m_000006_0, Status : FAILED
Task attempt_201310311057_0040_m_000006_0 failed to report status for 1225 seconds. Killing!
Task attempt_201310311057_0040_m_000006_0 failed to report status for 1249 seconds. Killing!
13/11/19 14:57:59 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputRead timed out
13/11/19 14:59:00 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputRead timed out
13/11/19 14:59:01 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 70% reduce 8%
13/11/19 14:59:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 71% reduce 8%
13/11/19 15:00:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 71% reduce 9%
13/11/19 15:01:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 71% reduce 10%
13/11/19 15:01:54 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 72% reduce 10%
13/11/19 15:02:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 73% reduce 10%
13/11/19 15:02:34 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201310311057_0040_m_000005_0, Status : FAILED
Task attempt_201310311057_0040_m_000005_0 failed to report status for 1212 seconds. Killing!
13/11/19 15:03:16 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 74% reduce 10%
13/11/19 15:04:08 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 75% reduce 10%
13/11/19 15:04:48 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 76% reduce 10%
13/11/19 15:06:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 77% reduce 10%
13/11/19 15:07:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 77% reduce 11%
13/11/19 15:07:46 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 78% reduce 11%
13/11/19 15:09:46 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 79% reduce 11%
13/11/19 15:10:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 79% reduce 12%
13/11/19 15:12:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 80% reduce 12%
13/11/19 15:12:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 81% reduce 12%
13/11/19 15:13:46 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 82% reduce 12%
13/11/19 15:14:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 83% reduce 12%
13/11/19 15:15:36 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 84% reduce 12%
13/11/19 15:16:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 85% reduce 12%
13/11/19 15:17:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 86% reduce 12%
13/11/19 15:18:45 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 87% reduce 12%
13/11/19 15:20:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 88% reduce 12%
13/11/19 15:22:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 89% reduce 12%
13/11/19 15:23:57 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201310311057_0040_m_000004_0, Status : FAILED
Task attempt_201310311057_0040_m_000004_0 failed to report status for 1378 seconds. Killing!
Task attempt_201310311057_0040_m_000004_0 failed to report status for 1292 seconds. Killing!
13/11/19 15:24:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 89% reduce 13%
13/11/19 15:25:08 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 79% reduce 13%
13/11/19 15:26:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 69% reduce 13%
13/11/19 15:28:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 70% reduce 13%
13/11/19 15:28:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 71% reduce 13%
13/11/19 15:29:06 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 71% reduce 12%
13/11/19 15:29:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 72% reduce 12%
13/11/19 15:30:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 73% reduce 12%
13/11/19 15:30:36 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201310311057_0040_m_000003_0, Status : FAILED
Task attempt_201310311057_0040_m_000003_0 failed to report status for 1203 seconds. Killing!
13/11/19 15:30:36 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201310311057_0040_m_000002_0, Status : FAILED
Task attempt_201310311057_0040_m_000002_0 failed to report status for 1200 seconds. Killing!
13/11/19 15:30:36 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201310311057_0040_r_000006_0, Status : FAILED
Task attempt_201310311057_0040_r_000006_0 failed to report status for 1202 seconds. Killing!
13/11/19 15:31:14 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 74% reduce 12%
13/11/19 15:31:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 75% reduce 12%
13/11/19 15:32:29 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 76% reduce 12%
13/11/19 15:33:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 77% reduce 12%
13/11/19 15:34:24 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 77% reduce 13%
13/11/19 15:34:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 78% reduce 13%
13/11/19 15:35:02 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 78% reduce 14%
13/11/19 15:35:34 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 79% reduce 14%
13/11/19 15:36:29 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 80% reduce 14%
13/11/19 15:36:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 80% reduce 15%
13/11/19 15:37:12 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 81% reduce 15%
13/11/19 15:37:46 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 82% reduce 15%
13/11/19 15:38:12 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 83% reduce 15%
13/11/19 15:38:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 84% reduce 15%
13/11/19 15:39:18 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 85% reduce 15%
13/11/19 15:39:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 86% reduce 15%
13/11/19 15:40:16 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 87% reduce 15%
13/11/19 15:40:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 88% reduce 15%
13/11/19 15:41:18 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 89% reduce 15%
13/11/19 15:41:48 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 90% reduce 15%
13/11/19 15:42:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 91% reduce 15%
13/11/19 15:43:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 92% reduce 15%
13/11/19 15:45:36 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 93% reduce 15%
13/11/19 15:46:29 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 93% reduce 16%
13/11/19 15:46:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 94% reduce 16%
13/11/19 15:48:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 94% reduce 17%
13/11/19 15:48:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 95% reduce 17%
13/11/19 15:50:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 96% reduce 17%
13/11/19 15:51:46 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 96% reduce 18%
13/11/19 15:52:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 97% reduce 18%
13/11/19 15:53:08 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 97% reduce 19%
13/11/19 15:56:03 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 97% reduce 20%
13/11/19 15:56:54 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 98% reduce 20%
13/11/19 15:57:10 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 98% reduce 21%
13/11/19 15:59:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 99% reduce 21%
13/11/19 16:02:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 21%
13/11/19 16:03:57 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 22%
13/11/19 16:30:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 23%
13/11/19 16:35:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 24%
13/11/19 16:40:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 25%
13/11/19 16:40:38 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 26%
13/11/19 16:44:38 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 27%
13/11/19 16:49:08 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 28%
13/11/19 16:49:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 29%
13/11/19 16:52:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 33%
13/11/19 16:53:54 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 38%
13/11/19 16:54:10 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 42%
13/11/19 16:55:21 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 43%
13/11/19 16:55:36 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 47%
13/11/19 16:55:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 56%
13/11/19 16:56:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 57%
13/11/19 16:58:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 58%
13/11/19 17:01:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 59%
13/11/19 17:04:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 64%
13/11/19 17:05:01 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 69%
13/11/19 17:07:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 70%
13/11/19 17:10:32 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 71%
13/11/19 17:13:21 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 72%
13/11/19 17:16:08 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 73%
13/11/19 17:19:03 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 74%
13/11/19 17:21:55 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 75%
13/11/19 17:24:46 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 76%
13/11/19 17:27:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 77%
13/11/19 17:30:24 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 78%
13/11/19 17:33:14 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 79%
13/11/19 17:36:07 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 80%
13/11/19 17:39:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 81%
13/11/19 17:41:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 82%
13/11/19 17:44:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 83%
13/11/19 17:47:27 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 84%
13/11/19 17:50:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 85%
13/11/19 17:53:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 86%
13/11/19 17:55:54 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 87%
13/11/19 17:58:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 88%
13/11/19 18:01:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 89%
13/11/19 18:04:21 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 90%
13/11/19 18:07:16 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 91%
13/11/19 18:10:08 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 92%
13/11/19 18:12:55 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 93%
13/11/19 18:15:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 94%
13/11/19 18:18:45 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 95%
13/11/19 18:21:36 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 96%
13/11/19 18:24:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 97%
13/11/19 18:27:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 98%
13/11/19 18:31:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 99%
13/11/19 18:41:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 100%
```

During this time (from map 100% reduce 0% to map 100% reduce 5%),  I observed that only 5 map tasks are completed (out of a total of 10), then the other 5 fail because of timeout. Then they re ran. I know this can be fixed by increasing the timeout, this is not the point of my question.

I know that in between Map and Reduce, what happens is that the data is being commited, shuffled and sort. First question. Is it normal having to wait so long between a map phase and a reduce phase with this data size? It doesn't feel right.

My reducer is kinda computationally heavy, so I changed it to an identity reducer. But this didn't seem to help much. Which makes me think that the problem is either in my mapper, or in the shuffling/sorting. So here's my mapper.

```
  public static class CliquesMapper extends
      Mapper<YearTermKey, SetWritable, YearTermKey, MapWritable> {

    private YearTermKey outputKEY=new YearTermKey();


    public void map(YearTermKey key, SetWritable value, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        Set<Writable> neighbors=value.keySet();
        int listSize=neighbors.size();
        if(listSize!=1){
            for(Writable keyTerm:neighbors){
                IntWritable KEYTerm=(IntWritable) keyTerm;
                outputKEY.set(new Text(key.getYear()), KEYTerm);
                MapWritable outputVALUE=new MapWritable();
                outputVALUE.put(key.getTerm(), value);                  
                context.write(outputKEY, outputVALUE);                                
            }
        }else{
            IntWritable finalTerm=new IntWritable();
            for(Writable t:neighbors){
                finalTerm.set(((IntWritable) t).get());
            }
            outputKEY.set(key.getYear(), finalTerm);
            NullWritable nw=NullWritable.get();
            MapWritable outputVALUE=new MapWritable();
            outputVALUE.put(key.getTerm(), nw);

            context.write(outputKEY,outputVALUE);

        }             
    }
  }
```

Second question. Is it possible that they the key-value pairs that i am emmiting from the mapper are causing this delay? Otherwise, why is this happening?

In any case, after all the 10 map tasks are completed (around map 100%, reduce 33%), the reducer takes nearly 2 hours to finish. How can this be possible given that it is an identity reducer?

Comment: Can you post the code for your Custom Writable's - this is most probably a GC / memory problem where you are not clearing previous state when the `readFields` methods is called

Answer (score 5):

You are asking several questions, and while they are related, they have different answers. I am answering them one-by-one below.

> Is it normal having to wait so long between a map phase and a reduce phase with this data size?

There's a barrier between the map and reduce phases. Your reducers cannot start until all your mappers finish. You have some mappers that are failing, thus slowing up your whole map phase and blocking the reduce phase. Once you solve that problem, your reduce phase should start earlier.

Why do your map tasks fail? Apparently they are not reporting progress:

```
[...] failed to report status for 1225 seconds. Killing!
```

> Is it possible that they the key-value pairs that i am emmiting from the mapper are causing this delay? Otherwise, why is this happening?

I am not sure, but I did take a look at your code and you can make it run faster as follows:

1) Convert your `Text` to `IntWritable`; it looks like it is numerical data (a year), and doing this will reduce the amount of data being sent from mapper to reducers. See Tip 5 in this [page on tips to improve Hadoop performance](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/12/7-tips-for-improving-mapreduce-performance/).

2) Re-use your writables. You are creating a `new Text` on each iteration. You'd be surprised how inneficient this is, and leads to awful performance due to the continuous creation/de-allocation of objects in the heap. The idea is to create a writable once, and then re-use it. For details, see Tip 6 in this [page on tips to improve Hadoop performance](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/12/7-tips-for-improving-mapreduce-performance/).

While I cannot be sure of this, I suspect this may the the reason why some of your mappers are failing. Garbage collection can cause your program to pause while it completes, and thus not report progress, and as a result Hadoop kills the task.

3) If you are not already doing so, use more than one reducer. See Tip 3 in the page I linked above for some heuristics on how to set an appropriate number of map and reduce tasks for your job.

> In any case, after all the 10 map tasks are completed (around map 100%, reduce 33%), the reducer takes nearly 2 hours to finish. How can this be possible given that it is an identity reducer?

This can be normal behavior if you have too much data for a single (or a few) reducers. Shuffling means sorting at the reduce side. Try to sort a large file in a Linux box using `sort`. It can take a LONG time. This is what is happening in your job.